# how to make gdbserver accept more than one connection?

Tags: gdb, kernel, qemu, gdbserver

I'm debugging an operating system (kernel + one user space application)  within qemu, using gdb connected to gdbserver. Since i'm in presence of two binaries, i would like to connect to gdbserver firstly with the kernel binary, and secondly with the user space binary so that i could switch from kernel tracing to user space tracing smoothly.
But, it seems that gdbserver can not accept more than one connection. Is it possible to get around this?

Comment: `gdbserver` is for user-space. Use KDB/KGDB for kernel-level debugging.

Comment: KDB/KGDB are too related to linux; my kernel has nothing to do with linux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the best way is to use the gdb command add-symbol-file to add userspace applications debugging information; provided you know their loading address. so to be precise, you have to launch the kernel debugging by connecting gdb to gdbserver as usual; and then, you can add those applications debugging information. You can also use .gdbinit script though. Read [this](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Files.html)

Answer (score 0):

QEMU's gdbstub only supports system/kernel level debugging, and only one connection at a time. However you should be able to run your one userspace app underneath a userspace gdbserver (running inside the guest), and connect a second gdb to that. (You might need to spend some time fiddling around to get the networking between the outside world and your guest system working if you haven't already got that sorted out.)

Comment: I think this workaround would be fine, but my kernel is not quite evolved now to support this feature. However thank you for your suggestion